# ORA-01007: variable not in select list while fetch c2 into cursor2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have oracle pl/sql procedure with below:

```
TYPE Paycomp2 IS RECORD(
        Row_Id           VARCHAR2(15),
        Created          DATE,
        Created_By       VARCHAR2(15),
        Last_Upd         DATE,
        Last_Upd_By      VARCHAR2(15),
        Modification_Num NUMBER(10),
        Conflict_Id      VARCHAR2(15),
        Comp_Price       NUMBER(10),
        Access_Level     VARCHAR2(30),
        Comp_Name        VARCHAR2(30),
        Depends_On       VARCHAR2(30),
        Gold_Cat         VARCHAR2(30),
        Order_Type       VARCHAR2(30),
        Parent_Id        VARCHAR2(15),
        Price_Plan       VARCHAR2(30),
        TYPE             VARCHAR2(30),
        Check_Flag       VARCHAR2(1),
    PREPAID_INIT_PRICE number(10),
    DB_LAST_UPD        date,
    DB_LAST_UPD_SRC    varchar2(50),
    Unit_Type        varchar2(30),
    M2M_CATEGORY        varchar2(30));
    TYPE Paycomp IS REF CURSOR;
    C2             Paycomp;
    Cursor2        Paycomp2;
```

when I do the below operation

```
FETCH C2 INTO Cursor2;
```

I am getting  this error :

> ORA-01007: variable not in select list  error.

This piece of script has worked previously.

How to resolve this issue?

script

```
Vordertype := 'Migration Prepaid - Postpaid';

Curcomp_Sql := Curcomp_Sql || Vordertype || '''' || ' union all ' || '' || Curcomp2sql || '' ||
                             Vordertype || '''';

OPEN C2 FOR Curcomp_Sql;

Sadmin.Pkg_Spliter.Prcsplitchar(Ppaycompstr, ';', Arrcomplist);

Vtotalcompprc := 0;
Arrcount      := Arrcomplist.Count;

BEGIN

Dbms_output.put_line('reached17');
    LOOP

       FETCH C2
            INTO Cursor2;
            Dbms_output.put_line('reached18');
        EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
        -- Processing each entry from Array
        Compfndflg := 0;
        dbms_output.put_line('arrCount 0:  reached');
        FOR Counter IN 1 .. Arrcount
        LOOP
            Vstrcommand := Arrcomplist(Counter);
            dbms_output.put_line('arrCount :  reached');
            Sadmin.Pkg_Spliter.Prcsplitchar(Vstrcommand, '?', Arrdisclist);
            IF Arrdisclist.Count <> 0 THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('arrCount :  reached1');
                -- Extracting the ? seperated values and putting them into variables
                Vcompname := Arrdisclist(1);
                --dbms_output.put_line(CURSOR2.comp_name||':- count -'||COUNTER||'--'||VCOMPNAME);
                BEGIN
                    -- Added by Accenture
                    IF Vcompname IS NOT NULL THEN
                        --dbms_output.put_line(CURSOR2.comp_name||':- count -'||COUNTER||'--'||ARRDISCLIST(1)||'-'||ARRDISCLIST(2)||'-'||ARRDISCLIST(3));
                        SELECT COUNT(0)
                        INTO   v_Count_Exist
                        FROM   Siebel.Cx_Paycomp_Mtx a, Siebel.Cx_Paycomp_Mtx b
                        WHERE  a.Row_Id = b.Parent_Id
                        AND    a.Order_Type = Vordertype
                        AND    b.Type = 'Payment Component'
                        AND    b.Comp_Name = Vcompname;
                        IF (v_Count_Exist = 0) THEN
                            Err_Msg    := 'Invalid Payment Component in String';
                            Result_Out := '74';
                            Errflg     := 1;
                            --dbms_output.put_line('Counter  2' || counter);
                            --dbms_transaction.rollback;
                            RAISE Error_Out;
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
                    --dbms_output.put_line('Counter  3' || CURSOR2.comp_name);
                    IF Vcompname = Cursor2.Comp_Name
                    --and  VCOMPNAME != '3'
                     THEN
                        Compfndflg := 1;
                        EXIT;
                    END IF;
                END;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
              ---DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VCOMPNAME, COMPFNDFLG'||VCOMPNAME||','||COMPFNDFLG);
        --dbms_output.put_line('CURSOR2.comp_name :'||CURSOR2.comp_name||' - COMPFNDFLG :'||COMPFNDFLG);
        IF Compfndflg != 1 THEN

            IF Temp_Comp_String IS NULL THEN
                Temp_Comp_String := Cursor2.Comp_Name || '?0?;';
                ---DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STRING 1'||TEMP_COMP_STRING);
            ELSE
                Temp_Comp_String := Temp_Comp_String || Cursor2.Comp_Name || '?0?;';
                ---DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STRING 2'||TEMP_COMP_STRING);
            END IF;
            --- END IF;
        ELSE

            IF Temp_Comp_String IS NULL THEN
                Temp_Comp_String := Arrdisclist(1) || '?' || Arrdisclist(2) || '?' ||
                                                        Arrdisclist(3) || ';';
                ---DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STRING 3'||TEMP_COMP_STRING);
            ELSE
                Temp_Comp_String := Temp_Comp_String || Arrdisclist(1) || '?' || Arrdisclist(2) || '?' ||
                                                        Arrdisclist(3) || ';';
                ---DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STRING 4'||TEMP_COMP_STRING);
            END IF;
            --            end if;
            --- END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;



 Curcomp_Sql VARCHAR2(2000) := 'SELECT mtx2.*
            FROM siebel.CX_PAYCOMP_MTX mtx1, siebel.CX_PAYCOMP_MTX mtx2
         WHERE mtx2.parent_id = mtx1.row_id
             AND mtx2.comp_name <> ''Security Deposit''
             AND mtx2.TYPE = ''Payment Component''
             AND mtx1.order_type = ''';


Curcomp2sql VARCHAR2(2000) := 'SELECT mtx2.*
            FROM siebel.CX_PAYCOMP_MTX mtx1, siebel.CX_PAYCOMP_MTX mtx2
         WHERE  mtx2.parent_id = mtx1.row_id
             AND mtx2.comp_name = ''Security Deposit''
             AND mtx2.TYPE = ''Payment Component''
             AND mtx2.depends_on = ''ACCESS LEVEL''
             AND mtx1.order_type = ''';
```

Comment: Show us the SELECT statement

Comment: Don't use `SELECT mtx2.*`.  Specify the entire list of columns you are selecting from `mtx2`, e.g. `SELECT mtx2.Row_Id, mtx2.Created, mtx2.Created_By, ...` etc.

Comment: The structure of your `CX_PAYCOMP_MTX` table has presumably changed, so selecting `*` from that no longer matches the record type. Why are you defining your own record type instead of using `%rowtype`? (Though spelling out the columns you need is probably better anyway). And why are you concatenating values into the query instead of using bind variables?

Comment: thanks! structure of the table has been changed... it helped me out to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version of what you're seeing, with a dummy table and simple anonymous block:

```
create table t42 (id number, some_value varchar2(10));

declare
  type t_rec is record(id number, some_value varchar2(10));
  l_rec t_rec;
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select * from t42';
  fetch l_cur into l_rec;
  close l_cur;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

To get the error you're seeing I just need to remove one of the table columns:

```
alter table t42 drop column some_value;
```

and run exactly the same code again:

```
declare
  type t_rec is record(id number, some_value varchar2(10));
  l_rec t_rec;
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select * from t42';
  fetch l_cur into l_rec;
  close l_cur;
end;
/

ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

The field list in the record type declared in the PL/SQL block no longer matches the column type in the cursor query. The record variable you're fetching into expects two columns (in my version; 22 in yours), but the query only gets one value.

You can (some would say *should*) specify all the columns you're selecting explicitly, but assuming you're actually referring to them all later you would then have done the equivalent of:

```
  open l_cur for 'select id, some_value from t42';
```

which would still have errored after the column removal, though a bit more helpfully perhaps:

```
ORA-00904: "SOME_VALUE": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

Since you're currently intending to get all columns from a single table, you could also have used [the `%rowtype`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-EBF66B92-8A94-4E3A-A837-253D5DA79D5F) syntax instead of your own record type:

```
declare
  l_rec t42%rowtype;
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select * from t42';
  fetch l_cur into l_rec;
  close l_cur;
end;
/
```

which with this trivial example runs successfully. You'll still have a problem though as soon as you refer to the removed column, assuming it's still part of the record:

```
declare
  l_rec t42%rowtype;
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_cur for 'select * from t42';
  fetch l_cur into l_rec;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.some_value);
  close l_cur;
end;
/

ORA-06550: line 7, column 30:
PLS-00302: component 'SOME_VALUE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 7, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

(Using `%rowtype` would give you some breathing space if a column was *added*, as it would just be ignored, unless and until you added code to refer to that record field. But with your code you'd get ORA-00932 inconsistent data types, rather than ORA-01007, so that doesn't seem to be what's happening here.)

If you aren't referring to the removed column/field anywhere then you shouldn't be selecting it anyway. Change the record type to only include the fields you actually need, and only get the corresponding columns in the cursor query.

If you are referring to the removed column/field then you're stuck anyway - you'll have find out what was removed and why, and then either fix your code to not refer to it (if that makes sense), or get that change reverted.